# Download .nc file with changing names

Tags: python, syntax, netcdf

I am downloading files from a internet source, that periodically change one specific string.
Ex: from "L8" to "L6"
In the file:

```
VT_OTT-V4-HGTHI-L6T09_T4_2682.nc
VT_OTT-V4-HGTHI-L6T09_T4_2683.nc
VT_OTT-V4-HGTHI-L6T09_T4_2684.nc
VT_OTT-V4-HGTHI-L4T12_T4_2685.nc
VT_OTT-V4-HGTHI-L9T07_T4_2686.nc
VT_OTT-V4-HGTHI-L4T12_T4_2687.nc
```

and so on...

I order to download files properly, I write the following line:

```
Level = int((path[path.find("L4T" or "L6T" or "L9T")+3:path.find("_T4")]))
```

(Level is changing, too, but I assign as a two-digit integer)

However, I get the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\\\\folder\\\\folder\\\\VT_OTT-V4-HGTHI-L4T09'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\folder\folder\script.py", line xx, in <module>
    Level = int((path[path.find("L4T" or "L6T" or "L9T")+3:path.find("_T4")]))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\\\\folder\\\\folder\\\\VT_OTT-V4-HGTHI-L4T09'
```

How would be the right syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the root of your problem:

```
path.find("L4T" or "L6T" or "L9T")
```

This part is equivalent to `path.find("L4T")` since `"L4T"` is a non-empty string and therefore "truthy." (Try `print("L4T" or "L6T" or "L9T")` to prove it to yourself.) The reason? `or` does not work the way you think it works, and function calls *definitely* do not work the way you think they work. (The argument to `find` is *fully evaluated* before `find` sees it, there's no way for `find` to see the `or`s in it.)

`str.find` returns `-1` if it can't find the substring. Since you are actually only looking for `"L4T"`, when the string doesn't contain that, you are throwing `-1` into the calculation, which means (after adding 3) your slice starts at index 2 of the path rather than the position of `LxT`. So you're actually trying to pass most of the path to `int()` and as you've seen, that doesn't work because that's not a number.

One way to solve this issue is with a regular expression:

```
re.search("L4T|L6T|L9T").start()
```

Or the equivalent:

```
re.search("L[469]T").start()
```

If you prefer not to use a regular expression, you could use `max()` to find the result that isn't `-1`:

```
max(path.find("L4T"), path.find("L6T"), path.find("L9T"))
```

Or, here is an excessively clever bit that relies on two of the `find`s returning `-1`. Don't actually do this, it's just for fun:

```
path.find("L4T") * path.find("L6T") * path.find("L9T")
```